# Facebook Graph API: Account access token vs Page access token data access expiration

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I obtain an access token for Facebook account and pages associated with this account. I get tokens for both an account and pages. After 90 days the token data access expires, it is mentioned in the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/
For the account after the expiration I get an empty response:

```
GET me/feed
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

For the page access token, I still can get the page's feed with the same request

```
GET /me/feed
```

Why is that so? Doesn't the data access expiration apply to Page tokens?

Comment: The page you referred to lists a bunch of page-related permissions for which it explicitly says data access will not expire.

Answer (score 0):

From [the link you quoted](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/), many of the permissions do not actually expire. These include:

- ads_read
- ads_management
- business_management
- configure_page_transactions
- pages_manage_ads
- pages_manage_cta
- pages_manage_instant_articles
- pages_manage_engagement
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_manage_posts
- pages_messaging
- pages_read_engagement
- pages_read_user_content
- pages_show_list
- read_audience_network_insights
- read_insights